# How to get list of database with condition in t-sql

Tags: t-sql

How can i get list of databases?
Select database if have table "test_table".

I don't now how to set condition in

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a dynamic query that checks sys.tables in each database.

```
declare @S1 nvarchar(max)
declare @S2 nvarchar(max)

set @S2 = ' union all select ''[DBNAME]'' from [DBNAME].sys.tables where name = ''test_table'''

select @S1 = stuff((select replace(@S2, '[DBNAME]',  quotename(name))
                    from master.dbo.sysdatabases
                    for xml path('')), 1, 11, '')

exec (@S1)
```